# Rails destroy action could not be found using nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources

I have a one to many relationship with menus and items. I have got a nested resource setup with the add and create actions for adding items to that specific menu. With a list of all items in that menu. All of that works fine, but I am having problems with the destroy action.

I get the error:
`The action 'destroy' could not be found for ItemsController`

As you can tell from the code below the destroy action is in ItemsController and is not under private so I do not know why it cannot be found.

### items_controller.rb

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_menu

  def create
    @item = @menu.items.create!(item_params)
    if @item.save
      redirect_to @menu, notice: "Item added!"
    else
      redirect_to @menu, warning: "Item failed!"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @item = @menu.items.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy
    redirect_to @menu, notice: "Item deleted!"
  end

  private

    def find_menu
      @menu = Menu.find(params[:menu_id])
    end

    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :price, :course, :vegetarian, :allergy, :menu_id)
    end

end
```

### ..views/menus/show.erb.html

```
  <tbody>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(item.price, unit: "£") %></td>
        <td><%= item.course %></td>
        <td><%= item.vegetarian %></td>
        <td><%= item.allergy %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Delete", [@menu, item], method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

### menus_controller.rb

```
def show
  @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
  @items = @menu.items
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
<td><%= link_to "Delete", [@menu, item], method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger" %></td>
```

should look like:

```
<td><%= link_to "Delete", menu_item_path(@menu, item), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger" %></td>
```